# How do I fix the problem with typing R-R in raw steno output?

Tags: json, keyboard, custom-keyboard

When I'm practicing the steno alphabet using Plover on [Joshua Grams' steno-jig Github site](https://joshuagrams.github.io/steno-jig/learn-keyboard.html), I'm unable to type the letter combination of R-R in the Left+Right steno-jig lesson.

I unchecked user.json and main.json, leaving only command.json ticked in Plover's settings. I think my settings are correct, but I still keep getting this error.I can type left R and right R (-R) one after another as R -R, but when I press R-R using raw steno output I get a spacebar hit instead of the intended output.

I tried to solve the problem by changing the main.json file by opening it with Microsoft Word and looking for the R-R output, but I couldn't find the output for that letter combination in the main.json file. Why can't I type R-R in raw steno output?